# JDBC No suitable driver found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to make a custom MySQL class in Java but I'm getting a few exceptions, here's my code:

MySQL.java:

```
package evo.common;

import java.sql.*;

public class MySQL {

private static String hostname;
private static String username;
private static String password;
private static String database;

public MySQL(String host, String user, String pass, String db)
{
    hostname = host;
    username = user;
    password = pass;
    database = db;
}

public static void Error(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println("Fatal Error: "+ex.getMessage());
}

public static void SQLError(SQLException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Fatal SQL Error: "+ex.getMessage());
}

private static Connection connect()
{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch(Exception e){
        Error(e);
    }

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+hostname+":3306/"+database;
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch(SQLException ex){
        SQLError(ex);
    }

    return conn;
}

public static ResultSet result(String query)
{
    Connection conn = connect();
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try
    {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
    } catch(SQLException ex){
        SQLError(ex);
    }

    return rs;
}

public static void main(String args[]){}
```

}

Test.java:

```
package evo.common;
import java.sql.*;
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    MySQL mysql = new MySQL("localhost", "root", "******", "souljaz");

    ResultSet res = mysql.result("SELECT * FROM users");
}
```

}

When I run Test I get these error messages in the console:

```
Fatal Error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Fatal SQL Error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/souljaz
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at evo.common.MySQL.result(MySQL.java:58)
at evo.common.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

I'm quite new to Java so help appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Do you have the MySQL JDBC driver .jar in your classpath?

Comment: Yes It's in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib if thats what you mean?

It works in a JSP file, I don't understand why it won't work in a standalone class file

Comment: Did you make sure that the program is executed with this specific JRE? btw, it is not a good practice to place 3rd party dependencies in your JRE lib directory (not very portable)

Comment: To break it down I'm using Eclipse as my IDE and I created a new Java project called "Classes" and made a standalone class called MySQL and Test.

Executed from the specified JRE? Sorry for my n00b'ism but I'm lost. I've come from PHP so all this is alien to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the lastest version of [Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and included it in your Classpath. If you are using an IDE this is only a matter of including the jar in your referenced libraries. If you are doing everything by hand, refer to this [official guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

```
java -cp "bin;lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin" evo.common.Test
```

**Update**:

**In Eclipse:** Right click your project in Package Explorer, then:

```
Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add JARS... (if lib is in the project)
                              or Add External JARS... (if it is external)
```

Comment: I've fixed it! Added mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar to classpath in project build path. Thanks.

Comment: Another question...

How can I use / include my MySQL.java file into a JSP file on a different project within Eclipse? Sorry for being a n00b if it was PHP I wouldn't be asking lol

Comment: User, try to use the search widget in the top right corner of the page. I'm sure that both of your questions (how to use a class inside JSP - which is not recommended in Javaland btw) and how to package and share resources between projects in Eclipse have already been answered in lots of of ways. If you really can't find an answer for it, open a specific question for each of yours problems and the community will take a look for you.