# "No suitable driver found" when trying to connect to SQL Server via JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I need to use JDBC to connect to SQL Server with Windows Authentication.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
String connect="jdbc:sqlserver://datababasehost:portnumber/databasename";       
Connection con=  (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connect,"username","password");
```

This is throwing an exception indicating "No suitable driver found".

What am I missing?

Comment: "No suitable driver found" means that Java could not find a driver that can handle a "jdbc:sqlserver://..." connection URL so you 'll need to fix that problem before you can connect *at all*, let alone with a particular type of authentication. You need to ensure that the .jar file for the JDBC driver (sqljdbc??.jar) is on your CLASSPATH or in the list of libraries associated with your project (e.g., Build Path in Eclipse).

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have the jar in my project folder. Trying to find the fix, to connect to the db.

Comment: Simply having the .jar file in your project folder is not necessarily sufficient. It needs to be in a place where Java will look for it, and Java is obviously not finding it because that's what the "No suitable driver found" error *means*.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to successfully connect to mysql DB without any issues, so I think there is no issue with jar.

Comment: (Oracle) MySQL and (Microsoft) SQL Server are completely different products that use different JDBC drivers. If you're trying to connect to an MS SQL Server instance with a MySQL JDBC driver then it simply will not work. What is the name of the .jar file you are trying to use?

Comment: Hi, Here is the name of the jar file, mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar

Comment: @gowthamjs23 You need to use the SQL Server JDBC Connector

Comment: That is a JDBC driver for MySQL. It does not recognize (or work with) SQL Server connections.

Comment: @gowthamjs23 Check this link to download the MSSQL JDBC Connector[JDBC for MSSQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)

Comment: Thank you, Gord. I have just downloaded the sqljdbc.jar, would see if I am still seeing any issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC No suitable driver found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882771/jdbc-no-suitable-driver-found)

Answer (score 0):

*(From comments to the question...)*

> Here is the name of the jar file, mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar

The MySQL JDBC driver cannot be used to connect to Microsoft SQL Server. The "No suitable driver found" error is occurring because Java cannot find an available JDBC driver that can handle a connection URL of the form

```
jdbc:sqlserver://...
```

You need to replace the MySQL JDBC driver with a JDBC driver that can connect to SQL Server, such as the [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt484311(v=sql.110).aspx).

Answer (score -2):

There is a very nice introduction: [HOW TO: Get Started with Microsoft JDBC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313100)

In short:

1. Download a driver from [Microsoft JDBC Drivers 6.0, 4.2, 4.1, and 4.0 for SQL Serve](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)
2. Install it somewhere
3. Make sure that the driver JAR is on your `CLASSPATH`
4. In your program, register the driver

   ```
   Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
   ```
5. Continue with the code, you already have.